# Share instance between AutoFac containers

Tags: c#, autofac, azure-service-fabric

I have an issue where I have a stateless service which has 2 AutoFac containers

I have a PriceService instance inside my container that is created the Main method of Program.cs

A second container is created inside my Startup.cs (unavoidable because different logic is required for setting up AutoFac for Web API)

This causes me an issue because when I go to resolve IPriceService I get a service that contains no data because a new instance is created by Startup

I have seen how to merge 2 containers together but how do I get hold of the Container that is created in my Program.cs Main method?

If I can get it I plan to create a new container that doesn't include IPriceService, then add my PriceService from the ServiceFabric container into my container that will be used by the Web API side

Has anyone ever tried anything like this?

**Extra Info**

My container has always been created in the Main method of Program.cs

I cant have 1 container because in order for AutoFac to be used for MVC/Controllers you need to integrate services that are only available in Startup classes

The startup class is not invoked at the right time so there is no way to get this extra information into my main container

*Additional Note*
I think the actual issue here may be a bit different, I am calling InstancePerCall when registering controllers.  This in turn seems to create a new instance of my service rather than using the existing one.  So maybe my question should be how can I avoid this?  I cant use a SingleInstance for controllers can I?

Comment: It would be easier to have only one container. Could you explain more why do you need 2 containers ? I guess it could be avoided

Comment: Have added extra info

Comment: @Paul. Sorry if I miss understand your use case but it seems very similar to the one of the functionality [CoherentSolutions.Extensions.Hosting.ServiceFabric](https://github.com/coherentsolutionsinc/aspnetcore-service-fabric-hosting) has.

Can you take a loot at the [hierarchical dependency injection](https://github.com/coherentsolutionsinc/aspnetcore-service-fabric-hosting/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection#hierarchical-dependency-injection) documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you register your service in Program.cs Main, you can inject it to Service Fabric Service constructor:

```
public MySFService(IMyRegistredService myRegistredService, StatelessServiceContext context) : base(context)
{
    this.myRegistredService = myRegistredService;
}
```

Then on WebHost creation you can register this service in WebAPI:

```
new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton(myRegistredService);
    })
    ...
```